# Audit Logins on PostgreSQL 9.0

Tags: audit

I have setup a script, created from various links on the web to trace activity in a table using a trigger.

```
/* Create the MinUser Table */
CREATE TABLE MinUser (
    User_Id             int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    User_Name           varchar (50) NOT NULL,
    User_Password           varchar (50) NOT NULL,
    User_Email          varchar (50),
    User_Role           varchar (50),
    UNIQUE (User_Name)
) WITH (OIDS=FALSE);


/* Create the Audit Table */
CREATE TABLE MinUser_Audit (
    AuditUser_Id            SERIAL,
        operation               char(1)   NOT NULL,
        stamp                   timestamp NOT NULL,
        userid                  text      NOT NULL,
        ipaddress                   text      NOT NULL,
    User_Id             int NOT NULL,
    User_Name           varchar (50) NOT NULL,
    User_Password           varchar (50) NOT NULL,
    User_Email          varchar (50),
    User_Role           varchar (50)
) WITH (OIDS=FALSE);

/* Function that will add a row to the MinUser_audit table when an insertion/deletion/modification is made to the MinUser table */
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MinUser_audit() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $usr_audit$
    BEGIN
        --
        -- Create a row in MinUser_Audit to reflect the operation performed on MinUser,
        -- make use of the special variable TG_OP to work out the operation.
        --
        IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
            INSERT INTO MinUser_audit (operation, stamp, userid, ipaddress, User_ID, User_Name, User_Password, User_Email, User_Role) VALUES ('D', now(), user, inet_client_addr(), OLD.User_Id,OLD.User_Name, OLD.User_Email, OLD.User_Password, OLD.User_Role);
            RETURN OLD;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
            INSERT INTO MinUser_audit (operation, stamp, userid, ipaddress, User_ID, User_Name, User_Password, User_Email, User_Role) VALUES ('U', now(), user, inet_client_addr(), NEW.User_Id,NEW.User_Name, NEW.User_Email, NEW.User_Password, NEW.User_Role);
            RETURN NEW;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
            INSERT INTO MinUser_audit (operation, stamp, userid, ipaddress, User_ID, User_Name, User_Password, User_Email, User_Role) VALUES ('I', now(), user, inet_client_addr(), NEW.User_Id,NEW.User_Name, NEW.User_Email, NEW.User_Password, NEW.User_Role);
            RETURN NEW;
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL; -- result is ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
    END;
$usr_audit$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


/* Create the trigger that will use the MinUser_audit() function */
CREATE TRIGGER MinUser_auditt AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON MinUser 
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE MinUser_audit();
```

I understand how to get the user name of the person who inserted/modified/deleted the record using user.  Is there a function I can use to get the ip address as well?  Also, is there a reference on PostgreSQL's website that shows all the different server variables that you can use in a query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the IP address you can use the function `inet_client_addr()`

All the system information functions are documented in the manual in the chapter "System Information Functions"

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html